AM5 Chart Column Opacity
I am trying to make a gradient opacity effect on my plot, however I am unable to target each columns' opacity separately, only by series.
          serie.columns.template.setAll({
            strokeOpacity: 0,
            cornerRadiusBR: 20,
            cornerRadiusTR: 20,
            cornerRadiusBL: 20,
            cornerRadiusTL: 20,
            fillOpacity: 0.8,
            width: am5.percent(100)
          });

Has anyone tried modifying the fillOpacity on the columns like this?

If anyone ever needs this, I found this to be the solution to my problem:
           serie.columns.template.adapters.add(
              'fillOpacity',
              function (fillOpacity, target) {
                return 0.7; // Return the opacity you want for each column
              }
            );

